# mvc Timeout Session_End

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application and I would like to redirect the user to the Home Screen just before the Session_End event fires?

If I allow it to go to session end then it just terminates the session and the page is no longer active.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: _"I would like to redirect the user to the Home Screen just before the [session expires]"_ - are you sure a redirect is the best option here? What if the user is currently editing a form?

Comment: I was thinking of displaying a message just before it times out this is why I wanted to know if there is a something that fires before the session end.

Comment: You could use the example below of setInterval/setTimeout but set it like 30 to 60 seconds before what a timeout would actually be. You could prompt the user that their session is about to expire in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea behind your question is just not let the session terminate automatically, you can do the following

In your _Layout.cshtml, include a keep-alive pinging script. I am showing in Razor syntax here -

```
@{
   // Get the session timeout from configuration
   var sessionTimeout = (System.Web.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState") as System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection).Timeout;
   // Ping interval can just a minute less that the session expiry
   var pingInterval = sessionTimeout.AddMinutes(-1.0);
}
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.setInterval(function () {
     $.ajax('@Url.Content("~")', { async: true, cache: false });
   }, @((int)pingInterval.TotalMilliseconds));
</script>
```

This script will ping your home page just one minute before the session expiry and thus kkeeping the session live.

Comment: If you're going to do this, then why not just make the session timeout at the max possible time?

Comment: I will have a look at this. Thanks

Comment: By doing the session keep alive in the way above, we can also introduce some conditional logic in there - like the session will be renewed if the user has some unsaved edits on the page etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` and `window.location.replace()`. The interval is in millisecond. So replace 3000 with with the interval you need.

```
setInterval(function(){
    window.location.replace(http://www.google.com)
}, 3000);
```

`setTimeout` will also be a viable option in this scenario (@Dismissle)

Comment: Wouldn't setTimeout be a better fit in this case?

Comment: They would both get the job done :-) In this scenario it would not matter really, since he wants to redirect when it hits. It will never run twice.

Comment: Thanks any other way doing it from the server.. rather than managing a variable as when a user changes page it will need to be reset ?

Comment: You could go about using SignalR, but this would again needs some js code at the client. The client actually does not have any direct connection to the server after the page has been loaded. Atleast not without using SignalR or something similar. You would just have to set the code posted above in the `document.ready`. You would not have to manage this in any way, if the timer hits, it redirects, otherwise it would not do anything.

Comment: As i have partial views in my application I'm assuming the document ready will need to be added to each page?

Comment: Don't you have a master layout? Or add it to a script bundle if you are using mvc4 or newer.